# Use one table or multiple tables for multiple client software system?

Tags: database, relational-database

This question may answer itself, but it is also a question of best practices.

I am designing an application that allows users (comapnies) to create an account.  Those users are placed in a table "Shop_table".  Now each shop has dynamic data, however the tables would be the same for each shop, like `shop_employees`, `shop_info`, `shop_data`.

Would it be more effective to have a specific table for each shop or would I just link their data by the shop id.

For example:

```
shop: Dunkins with id:1 
shop: Starbucks with id:2
```

would dunkins have its own `dunkins_shop_employees`, `dunkins_shop_info`, `dunkins_shop_data` tables
and Starbucks have its own `starbucks_shop_employees` , `starbucks_shop_info` , `starbucks_shop_data`

or would i have one table  `shope_employees`, `shop_info`, `shop_data` and link by id 1 or 2, etc..

Comment: I would definetely recommend 1 table link by id.  It'll be easier to maintain when you need to add table or alter the table

Comment: Also, don't have the name table in a table name unless it only makes sense that way   :P

Comment: Thannks and @SpectralGhost i used that for freely because to make the question simple :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely one table for each *entity* with a field to identify the company.

If all the companies have the same information there is no need to create tables for each, and if you did your queries will become a nightmare.

Do you really want a load of UNION queries in order to get any aggregate data across companies? You will also have to modify *all* queries in your DB as soon as another company (and therefore multiple tables) are added.

Define your tables independently, model the entities you want to store and dont think about who they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one table ( for each `shop_info` etc.. )

Creating similar tables is a maintenance nightmare. You will need to create similar foreign keys, similar constraints, similar indexes, etc.

If your concern is privacy, this should be controlled in your application. You application should always add a "WHERE" clause based on who is logged in/ querying.

If you absolutely need to - you can create views which where clause as shop_id. You can give rights to various people on the view only. This would only make sense if you had a big customer who wanted some SQL level query ability.